Windows 10 WSL Colors
I have a Windows 10 PC whose WSL terminal has text colors that are too bright.
Have tried WSL on other Win10 machines and the text colors are dimmer and easier to read.
Is there a setting that makes the WSL terminal colors dimmer or softer?
This issue is not just limited to the ls command output, it's the terminal colors, at least in bash.
See the difference: (1st one too bright, 2nd one just right)



WSL itself doesn't actually have its own terminal, so there may be several possibilities:

On Windows 10, which you are running, the default terminal is the legacy Windows Console Host (conhost.exe)
It's possible to change the color settings for Console Host by clicking the icon in the upper left corner and selecting Properties (for the current session) or Default (for future sessions).  It could also be something like the opacity setting throwing things off.

On recent Windows 11 versions, the default terminal is the drastically improved Windows Terminal.  However, it's also possible to install Windows Terminal on Windows 10.
Windows Terminal includes about a dozen color themes out-of-the-box, and you can define additional ones as well.  The Ubuntu distribution actually installs its own theme, so it may even depend on how you installed Ubuntu.


It's even possible to be running another terminal, although only the two mentioned above, to my knowledge, have the ability to set themselves as default, and you'd almost certainly know if you were running something different.

don't recall how i installed ubuntu on one vs another host. maybe one was from msft store and the other was the older wsl1 with ubuntu 18 upgraded to 22. too many variables and only so much time to devote to this. did not know about the terminal differences so thanks for the edifying reply.

Simple short answer:
Also the easiest...
Turn down your monitor's contrast setting.
Note: The actual settings in "WSL" are likely the very same on both machines.

monitor contrast may help but those screenshots were taken from the same monitor. so something is different on this system, some esoteric wsl or windows setting. i'll live with it. thanks
